# How to declare List to be populated with 5 tables join

Tags: c#, sql, list

I have this query below. After that, I want to populate a list with the results. How should I do ?

```
var query = from cust in context.Customer
            join city in context.Cities on cust.id_city equals city.id
            join state in context.State on city.id_state equals state.id
            join reg in context.Region on state.id_region equals reg.id
            select new 
            {
               nameCust = cust.name,
               nameCity = city.name,
               nameState = state.name,
               nameRegion = reg.name
            };
```

Comment: If I try to use ToList() I receive the following error :  'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: ToList() over *whole* statement

Comment: As @jim said, call .ToList() over the entire query: `var query = (from cust ...).ToList();` This will give you a list with an anonymous type as the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call `ToList()` on the return value:

```
var queryResult = (from cust in context.Customer
            join city in context.Cities on cust.id_city equals city.id
            join state in context.State on city.id_state equals state.id
            join reg in context.Region on state.id_region equals reg.id
            select new 
            {
               nameCust = cust.name,
               nameCity = city.name,
               nameState = state.name,
               nameRegion = reg.name
            }).ToList();
```

I'm wondering though, if you are using Entity Framework. If so: this might be a bether solution:

```
var queryResult = context.Customer
    .Include(customer => customer.City)
    .Include(customer => customer.State)
    .Include(customer => customer.Region)
    .ToList();
```

**( ! )** Keep in mind you are loading a complete table into memory using `ToList()`

Comment: If you're going to use the answer already provided in the question's comments, then provide some explanation.